# Initialization vector - DES/triple-des algorithm

Tags: c#

In order to generate the encrypted data we would need to define a Key that should suffice generating the data. But in .net DESCryptoServiceProvider requires Key and Intialisation Vector to generate the encrypted data. In this regard, I would like to know the importance & the benefit gained by defining this initialisation vector field. Is this mandatory while encryption using DES algorithm.

Pls share your thoughts on the same.

Regards,
Balu

Answer (score 0):

If a key is used to encrypt multiple items that happen to be the same (or start out the same) without an initialization vector, you'll get the same ciphertext output, which is a pretty big problem.

Using a unique initialization vector for each item that's encrypted solves that problem.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Initialization_vector_.28IV.29 for a bit more detail.